# How do i execute a remote script with 'screens'?

Tags: ssh, shell-script, gnu-screen

I need to execute a script locally. The problem is, it needs to use `screen` and send the ctrl d command.

How would i do this? The script will be on my local windows machine. i can use winscp, putty, mingw and other apps.

Comment: Assuming you mean `Ctrl-a d` for immediately detaching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) ([expect home page](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), included in most unix software distributions) to script interactions with programs that run in text terminals.

However, there's probably a simpler way of doing what you're trying to do. You can send commands to a screen session from any command line, and you can use screen's `stuff` command to insert input into a screen window. See [Why is screen seemingly doing nothing with commands passed with -X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5847/why-is-screen-seemingly-doing-nothing-with-commands-passed-with-x), [Sending input to a screen session from outside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/sending-input-to-a-screen-session-from-outside) for examples.

```
screen -S sessionname -p windowname -X stuff $'\004'
```

If this answer isn't helping you, give more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

From screen(1) manual

> ```
>    -d|-D [pid.tty.host]
>         does not start screen, but detaches the elsewhere running screen
>         session. It has  the same  effect  as typing "C-a d" from screen’s
>         controlling terminal. -D is the equivalent to the power detach key.
>         If no session can be detached, this option is ignored. In combination
>         with the -r/-R option more powerful effects can be achieved:
> ```

I usually use `screen -AmdS sessionname commandline` to run a commandline in a screen session and immediately detach. e.g. running a screen from a cronjob

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -AmdS shoutcast /home/foo/sc_serv /home/foo/sc_serv.conf
```

Adding new commands on an existing detached screen and detach immediately.

```
screen -dr sessionname -X commandline
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrangement doesn't make any sense to me. Are you asking how to send keys to screen from something outside screen? You might use `expect` for that senario. You can also launch screen with a custom config file to change the ctrl-d to something easier to send.