# How to get the output inside `screen` out to a script?

Tags: bash, logs, gnu-screen, recording

I have a `screen` instance running, and I would need to execute some code inside the `screen`, and get the result out to my script.

The first part is quite easy, I just `screen -S session_name -X eval 'stuff "$cmd"\015'`.
(I modified [a line I found in a script](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server_startup_script))

The second part, getting out the output, is trickier. How can I get the whole output, whatever it's size?

Comment: Related: [explanation of `screen -X stuff …`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5847); [a question similar to yours](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305).

Comment: Thanks :) The second link was explained why the first command has to be `stuff`, which was what I had trouble understanding.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could start `screen` with the `-L` option.  This will cause screen to create a file `screenlog.n` (the n part is numerical, starting with a zero) in the current working directory.

In your case this would look something like: `screen -S session_name -L -X eval 'stuff "$cmd"\015'`

As long as you remember to clean up afterwards, this should match what you are after.

For last line of the log, it can easily be obtained with `tail -1 screenlog.0`, or the entire log can be parsed however you wish.

Comment: One thing, though: the `screen` command I gave was just to send the command in. To start the `screen`, I used `screen -dmS name program` ;-)

Answer (score 29):

One more nuance that may be helpful in the future: If you're in a screen session, you can interactively ask for the log file to be created. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> (Control-A followed by capital H) to ask screen to start dumping whatever window you're in to a log file.

Comment: Don't know if it is because of a newer version but my `man screen` says, I have to type C-A H, without the Control for the H. Sad only, that this doesn't capture the previous log.

Comment: You're right! It's C-A H to generate a log file. Please note that it's capital H (lowercase h produces just a hardcopy of the current screen).

Comment: Please update the answer to C-A H. Future searchers may be mislead and miss the correct answer.

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to send the command through a script? As in send control+a and then the H after a split second.