# Trouble sending command to detached Screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to send a command to a screen session and if possible get the output.

My attempt at sending a command to a screen session is as I found on this website and lots of others, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
root@server [~]# screen -X "script -a -c 'ls -l' /tmp/command.log" && cat /tmp/command.log
cat: /tmp/command.log: No such file or directory
root@server [~]#
```

Note there is only 1 Screen session running, so I have omitted -S and -p (tried it with those too and no effect). For example:

```
root@server [~]# screen -p 0 -X stuff "script -a -c 'ls -l' /tmp/command.log" && cat /tmp/command.log
cat: /tmp/command.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending text input to a detached screen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen)

Comment: You seem to be missing a `stuff`, and you do need `-p`.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work though. Could you check my input? (I'm editing my post)

Comment: Ah, there's another problem, so this isn't a duplicate after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, read [sending text input to a detached screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen). You do need `-p` to direct the input to the right window. Also, the command won't be executed until you stuff a newline (CR or LF, the interactive shell running inside screen accepts both). That's:

```
screen -p 0 -X stuff "script -a -c 'ls -l' /tmp/command.log$(printf \\r)" &&
cat /tmp/command.log
```

There's a second problem, which is that the `screen -X stuff …` command completes as soon as the input has been fed into the screen session. But it takes a little time to run that `script` command. When `cat /tmp/command.log` executes, it's likely that `script` hasn't finished; it might not even have started yet.

You'll need to make the command running inside `screen` produce some kind of notification. For example, it could signal back that it's finished, assuming that the shell within Screen is running on the same machine as Screen.

```
sh -c '
  sleep 99999999 &
  screen -p 0 -X stuff "\
script -a -c \"ls -l\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
"
  wait
  cat /tmp/command.log
'
```

Comment: That's a workaround and a half! Anyway thank you very much. This does the trick perfectly. Will tick as soon as possible :)

Comment: How would I go about swapping ls -l for $1?

Comment: @JamesHadley I don't understand the question.