# Grab text from detached screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am working on a collectd plugin to monitor a program I have running in a detached screen session. This program constantly updates the terminal with its status by replacing its old status (similar to programs like top, etc).

I would like to be able to grab what it is currently "showing" and parse it to get the current status of the program. I know there is a way to send text to a screen, but is there a way to grab it? Alternatively, is there another program/approach to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be the `hardcopy` command.

```
screen -x yoursession -X hardcopy /path/to/your/file
```

Would cap what the terminal is currently showing, without backlog, to the given file.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like

```
 screen -Xx <screen_nr> hardcopy outfile.txt
```

what you are looking for?

Also take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63809/gnu-screen-print-a-detached-session-to-stdout).