# Send very long commands to detached screen results in "ERROR remote control too long"

Tags: gnu-screen

I have long commands to send to a detached `screen`. I used :

```
screen -x screen-name -p 1 -X stuff 'mycommand\n'
```

As inspired by this [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen). It works, but if `mycommand` is very long I get the screen error :

> remote control too long

I cannot cut the command in smalled bits. It is like:

```
( { script1.sh; script2.sh; } </dev/null &>/dev/null &)
```

with many scripts and `mv` operations between the scripts.

So, how could I make `screen` to accept these long command lines? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can put any long command in a shell script with a short name and then pass the short name of the shell script to screen

Comment: @HBruijn yes I might end up doing that, tough given my number of processes it can become a bit messy... I am still considering my options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen's `stuff` command does not run commands, it emulates typing. It sounds like you have a shell running in the screen session, which is reading what it believes to be typing and running it when it receives a newline.

So you can cut the command into small bits; you could send it one character at a time if you want. The shell inside the screen won't run it at least until you send the final character, the `\n`.

(That said, it's probably much easier to put the whole thing in a shell script file then either run or source it).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that I could continue pasting in the same `screen` line as long as I do not send a `\n`! So that `screen -x screen-name -p 1 -X stuff 'mycommand\n'` and : `screen -x screen-name -p 1 -X stuff 'myco'` `screen -x screen-name -p 1 -X stuff 'mmand\n'` are equivalent