# Return Carriage not working (Screen)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, gnu-screen

When I execute the command `screen -S myscreen -X stuff $'search add $1 \015'` from a shell it works perfectly. If I put it in a .sh file and run it as `sh /test.sh variablehere` it sends it to screen as `$'search add variablehere'`.

Why would it normally work but not from `sh`? Im on Ubuntu Server if it matters.

Comment: Found a solution, still not sure why it refused to work. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5847/why-is-screen-seemingly-doing-nothing-with-commands-passed-with-x

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? So that you can accept it when possible and "close" the question.

Comment: The problem in the other question appears to be different to me. If it "solved" your problem it's only because it sidestepped your issue, which seems to be that `bash != sh`. You can't do fancy stuff in bash and exect it to work the same in a different shell, but you can build and run scripts with bash so it should be an easy fix.

Comment: @MaxMackie, I did but it added it as a comment. No need to now as enzotib provided a good explanation of not only how to fix the issue but why it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `$'search add $1 \015'`, and in general the quoting `$'string'` is a `bash` features (probably also of other shells), so it works from command line, where you probably are using `bash`.

It for sure do not work for `sh`, that in ubuntu points to `dash`.

So the simple solution is to invoke your script with `bash ./test.sh`.

Comment: Apparently it points to `dash` because running it with `bash` worked just fine. Thanks.